# Repeat last yank

Tags: cut-copy-paste, register, repeated-commands

I'm appending text to "a" register with:`"AyW`.
If I wanted to repeat last change I would use:`.` But in this case I would like to repeat the last **yank** command.
Is there a command to repeat the last yank (append)? or should I use `q` to record a macro instead?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you include the flag `y` in the `cpoptions` option;

```
set cpoptions+=y
```

then yanks may be repeated using `.`.  See `:help cpo-y`:

```
                            *cpo-y*
    y   A yank command can be redone with ".".
```

Comment: Wow, I started writing up a really long hacky vimscript answer, but this is so much better. +1